# Cropper: what is the meaning of '.selector'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside [fengyuanchen](https://github.com/fengyuanchen)'s [Cropper plugin](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/) [main.js file](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/e894c0c6e627d90edb06181f4c887a1a6e4d394a/examples/crop-avatar/js/main.js) there is a line of code:

`201: preview: this.$avatarPreview.selector,`

I haven't seen `.selector` before, what does it do?

sorry guys. couldnt find it myself =(

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.selector` is a [jQuery property](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) which should return the selector used when the object set was created.

`var selector = $('#container').selector; //thing would be '#container'`

This has been deprecated in [jQuery 1.7](https://api.jquery.com/selector/), I would suggest that the author of the plugin be notified and that they stop using it.

> The .selector property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only maintained to the extent needed for supporting .live() in the jQuery Migrate plugin. **It may be removed without notice in a future version**.

Answer (score 0):

.selector refers to the jQuery selector here.([cropper/readme](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/2fb61370dfd9537ce9d4096cb0d0fac3573fd46e/README.md))

```
preview

Type: String (jQuery selector)
Default: ''
```

To know more about selectors, you should visit jQuery official website.([seletor](https://api.jquery.com/selector/))

Hope this hepls!